# Flutter release apk show blank screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I wrote *my first* flutter app and It works very well on the simulator in the debug mode. but when I extract it as a release apk and install it on my phone it shows only a blank screen!
I tried different solutions online but nothing worked. I tried to add each `row` and `column` in a `Expanded` widget but this didn't work. and there is no errors in the debug console (vscode).

### Here is what I have in the debug console:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:33885/Z0RCbF0ZTYY=/ws
D/EGL_emulation(19403): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa043e6e0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x91544a50)
Application finished.
Exited (sigterm)
```

### This is my `main` file:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:currency_converter/CurrencyInput.dart';
import 'package:currency_picker/currency_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

const String API_KEY = "51a7c9772f10302ec8ec08ce77cf73e3";
late var currency_rates_json;
void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Currency Converter',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

Future<http.Response> fetchRates() {
  return http.get(
    Uri.parse('http://api.exchangeratesapi.io/v1/latest?access_key=$API_KEY'),
  );
}

double calculate(double amount, Currency from, Currency to) {
  return currency_rates_json["rates"][to.code.toUpperCase()] *
      amount /
      currency_rates_json["rates"][from.code.toUpperCase()];
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CurrencyInput input1 = CurrencyInput(),
        input2 = CurrencyInput(
          isEnabled: false,
        );
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchRates(),
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
            return const Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            currency_rates_json = json.decode(snapshot.data!.body);
            return Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
              body: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80, left: 20, right: 20),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Convert",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 50,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 70,
                    ),
                    input1,
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    input2,
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 50,
                        horizontal: 30,
                      ),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 23, vertical: 10)),
                          onPressed: () {
                            double? val = double.tryParse(input1.getText);
                            if (val != null) {
                              input2.setText(
                                calculate(
                                  val,
                                  input1.getCurrency,
                                  input2.getCurrency,
                                ).toString(),
                              );
                            }
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            "Calculate",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

### This is my `CurrencyInput.dart` file:

```
import 'package:currency_converter/FlagCurrencyButton.dart';
import 'package:currency_picker/currency_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class CurrencyInput extends StatefulWidget {
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  bool isEnabled;
  Currency currency = CurrencyService().findByCode('egp')!;
  String get getText => textEditingController.text;
  Currency get getCurrency => currency;
  late void Function(String) setText;
  late void Function(String) setCurrency;
  CurrencyInput({
    this.isEnabled = true,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<CurrencyInput> createState() => _CurrencyInputState();
}

class _CurrencyInputState extends State<CurrencyInput> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    widget.setText = (String value) {
      setState(
        () {
          double? tmp = double.tryParse(value);
          assert(tmp != null);
          widget.textEditingController.text =
              double.parse(tmp!.toStringAsFixed(4)).toString();
        },
      );
    };

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 3),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            FlagCurrencyButton(
              CurrentCurrency: widget.currency,
              CurrencyChanged: (Currency cur) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.currency = cur;
                });
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 4,
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: widget.textEditingController,
                enabled: widget.isEnabled,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: [
                  // FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"[0-9.]")),
                  TextInputFormatter.withFunction(
                    (oldValue, newValue) {
                      return newValue.text.isEmpty
                          ? newValue
                          : double.tryParse(newValue.text) == null
                              ? oldValue
                              : newValue;
                    },
                  ),
                ],
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 22,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 12,
            ),
            Text(
              widget.currency.symbol,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### This is my `FlagCurrencyButton.dart`:

```
import 'package:country_flags/country_flags.dart';
import 'package:currency_picker/currency_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FlagCurrencyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Currency CurrentCurrency;
  final Function(Currency) CurrencyChanged;
  const FlagCurrencyButton({
    required this.CurrentCurrency,
    required this.CurrencyChanged,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        showCurrencyPicker(
          context: context,
          showFlag: true,
          showSearchField: true,
          showCurrencyName: true,
          showCurrencyCode: true,
          favorite: [],
          onSelect: (Currency currency) {
            CurrencyChanged(currency);
          },
        );
      },
      child: Row(
        children: [
          CountryFlag.fromCountryCode(
            CurrentCurrency.code.substring(0, 2),
            height: 37,
            width: 50,
            borderRadius: 8,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Text(
            CurrentCurrency.code.toUpperCase(),
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: One reason may be the futureBuilder is unable to build as there might be no internet permission. So, can you please try adding internet permission in androidmanifest.xml and try.
Secondly, you can replace your future builder with any static widget and check if the widget is shown or not.

Comment: @VinamraJaiswal Yub when I added the internet permission in the `AndroidManifest`. It worked very well. I totally forgot that it will need permission to access the internet. Thanks a lot